# Is this a valid CSS Selector?

Tags: css, dom, css-selectors, pseudo-class

With-respect to the following expression:

```
radio:focus > .approve, radio:focus > .dis-approve{/*statements...*/}
```

Is it accepted by CSS interpreter/compiler?

Objective: applies iff both .approve and .dis-approves' radio-typed parents are in-focus.

Comment: writing `radio` you mean "`radio'` type `input`"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is TWO selectors to which you are applying the same properties...not a single selector.

Comment: It's not valid HTML. `radio` is not an element, do you mean `input type="radio"`? And I don't think you can nest elements inside `inputs`.

Comment: Probably you are looking for the following: `[type="radio"]:focus + .approve, [type="radio"]:focus  + .dis-approve { /*...*/ }` or maybe `[type="radio"]:focus ~ .approve, [type="radio"]:focus  ~ .dis-approve { /*...*/ }`? Check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) what [+](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) and [~](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp) mean.

Comment: provide the HTML structure too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is *valid* (see [BoltClock's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47673589/is-this-a-valid-css-selector/47673896?noredirect=1#comment82334946_47673896)), but you'll find that it will not match anything as it has several problems:

1. `radio` isn't a valid HTML element. Did you mean `input[type=radio]`?
2. If you did mean `input[type=radio]`, that element cannot have children, so `> .approve` and `> .dis-approve` wouldn't select anything. Did you mean `+ .approve` and `+ .dis-approve`, to an element next to this one?

The best way to know if your CSS works is to apply your CSS to a HTML structure which should accompany this and see what happens.

Comment: "Invalid" and "won't match anything" are not the same thing. A valid selector that matches nothing will not invalidate all other selectors in a list (and therefore the entire ruleset). In this case, neither selector in the list will match anything, so it makes no difference, but the leading "No." in the answer seems incorrect if interpreted as an answer to "Is it accepted by CSS interpreter/compiler?" The rest of the answer is fine, though, because "Is it accepted by CSS interpreter/compiler?" is almost certainly not the question the asker wanted to ask.

Comment: @BoltClock great response! My answer was admittedly very lazy. I've updated my answer to link to your comment as an explanation of why it's valid, but almost certainly not something which will select OP's markup.